# Evaluator in OCaml/ML

Tags: ocaml, ml, evaluator

```
type bool_exp =
    TT
  | FF
  | Var of string
  | And of bool_exp * bool_exp
  | Not of bool_exp ;;

 eval : bool_exp -> (string -> bool) -> bool
```

I am trying to write an evaluator function called `eval`. I am very new to OCaml and not used to the syntax. Where can I start in writing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main device when working with datatypes like your `bool_exp` is *pattern-matching*. That is, for every possible case of the input to your function you specify its behaviour separately. A skeleton for your `eval` function could look like

```
let rec eval e env =
  match e with
    TT -> ...
  | FF -> ...
  | Var x -> ...
  | And (e1, e2) -> ...
  | Not e
;;
```

The first argument `e` is the expression that should be evaluated, and the second `env` is often called an *environment*, mapping variables (represented by strings) to values (here just Boolean constants).

The `rec` is needed whenever the defined function is recursive (i.e., using itself in the function body), and since your datatype is defined recursively, also `eval` will be recursive. E.g., in order to evaluate `And (e1, e2)` you will first have to know the values of `e1` and `e2` w.r.t. the same environment.

This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with Chris' answer, your function will look pretty much exactly like this:

```
let rec eval e env =
  match e with
    TT -> true
  | FF -> false
  | Var x -> x env
  | And (e1, e2) -> (eval e1 env) && (eval e2 env)
  | Not e -> not (eval e env) ;;
```

Then while running the code to test it, you will declare a function called env, like this:

```
let env y = true;;
```

Or...

```
let env y = false;;
```

Since the type is "eval : bool_exp -> (string -> bool) -> bool", you need to define what the function for (string -> bool) is before you use the function.

So,

```
1. Declare data type bool_exp.
2. Declare that function I gave you.
3. Declare env as a function, either one you want, there's only two possible ones.
4. You can now use the function.
```

Merry functional programming to you. =)

Comment: While your answer is surely correct, the OP sounds like a homework assignment. In such cases we shouldn't "spoil all the fun" by providing a full solution.